# Multiple event listener are added to each element resulting in multiple ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I've got a list of shopping cart.
Each cart contain a list of products.

```
{# templates\Cart\list.twig #}
{% use 'Cart/details.twig' %}
{% extends '@templates/_base.twig' %}
   {% block body %}
      <div class="list-group" id="cart-list" role="tablist">
         {% for cart in cart_list %}
            <a class="products-list-cart list-group-item list-group-item-action {% if userCart.current %}active{% endif %}"
                               id="item-details-cart-{{ cart.id }}"
                               href="#products-list-cart-{{ cart.id }}"
                               data-href="{{ path('cart_product_list', {'cart_id':cart.id}) }}"
                               data-toggle="list" role="tab" aria-controls="products-list-cart-{{ cart.id }}"
                               {% if not first_cart %}data-product-list-loaded="true" {% set first_cart = true %}{% endif %}>
               See cart details for cart {{ cart.id }}
               {# 
                  On click, make an ajax call to filled
                  in product list '#products-list-cart-{{ cart.id }}'
               #}
            </a>
         {% endfor %}
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content" id="carts-content">
         {% for cart in cart_list %}
            {% set userCart = cart.userCart %}
            <div class="tab-pane fade {% if userCart.current %}show active{% endif %}"
                                 id="products-list-cart-{{ cart.id }}"
                                 role="tabpanel"
                                 aria-labelledby="cart-{{ cart.id }}">
               {% if not first_cart_product_list %}
                  {% block cart_details %}
                     {{ parent() }} 
                  {% endblock %}
               {% else %}
                  <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-1x fa-fw">&nbsp;</i> {{ "loading_product"|trans }}
                  ... {# 
                        Filled in on click on '.products-list-cart'.
                        Proceed to ajax call.
                      #}
               {% endif %}
            </div>
         {% endfor %}
      </div>
   {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('cart') }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('product') }}
{% endblock %}
```

I try to keep it simple, I use [list tab bootstrap component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/#javascript-behavior).

The problem come when i have to include entry point.

Because my javascript add event listener to product details.
So all product details for first cart work fine, because they are loaded on page load.
This behaviour is managed by `first_cart_product_list` variable.

All other products list are displayed when user click on a cart to see its details.
The problem is that the entry point which include the javascript only add event to element which are load with the dom.

I've try to add the entry point to my `Cart/details.twig` template but it get loaded on each ajax call.
So here the problem is that all ajax call add event listener to all existing `$('a.products-list-cart')` element. So a lot of element on the page got more and more event listener instead of one.

I give you an example :
If i add the `encore_entry_script_tags` to cart details template :

```
{# Cart/details.twig #}
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('product') }}
```

It get added on each product list and so :
If i have 4 carts :

[image]

And i click on each one to load product list which add a event listener on each product on the page.
So for the first cart i'll have 4 event listener on each product element.

Result is that when i click on 'add to cart' button for first cart :

[image]

There is 4 call to a ajax function which update product quantity into cart.

```
// product.js entry point...
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('.btn-add-product-to-cart').on( // This event listener is added to every button on product list
            'click',
            function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: $(this).data('href'),# Call controller route to modify product quantity in DB
                ...
```

I've try to use the [.one()](https://api.jquery.com/one/) function because i want only one event listener to be added on each elements. But unfortunately it does not work.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: _“The problem is that the entry point which include the javascript only add event to element which are load with the dom.”_ - and the proper solution to this well-known problem, is called _event delegation_.

Comment: I don't know event delegation, i'll give it a look. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can easily accomplish that doing an [.off](https://api.jquery.com/off/#off-events-selector-handler) the event before you add the event. For the click event would be something like this:

```
$('a.products-list-cart').off('click').click(function () { ... })
```

Comment: Yes i agree this is possible, but so javascript will have extra work to do. If i just set off it retire all previously added listener. Then it'll newly add all event listener.

If I got 5 items it's ok but when i'll got 500 it's not suitable :|